# Returning JSON via WebApi

Tags: c#, json, httpclient

I am using the HttpClient in C# to try and integrate SSO (Single Sign On) into some of our custom Applications.

I have done this successfully in our JavaScript Apps, but I'm having some difficulty integrating it into some of our Umbraco sites.

My code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;

namespace Umbraco.WebApi
{
  public class TestController : UmbracoApiController
  {

    public  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<Object> GetRefreshToken(Token t)
    {
      try {
        string refToken = t.refresh_token;

        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
          { "grant_type", "refresh_token" },
          { "client_id", "CLIENTID" },
          { "client_secret", "CLIENTSECRET" },
          { "refresh_token", refToken }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);        
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://URL.org/Token", content);

        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return responseString;

      } catch(HttpRequestException e) {
        return e;
      }
    }

    public class Token
    {
      public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    }

    public class AuthData
    {
      public string access_token { get; set; }
      public string token_type { get; set; }
      public int expires_int { get; set; }
      public string refresh_token { get; set; }
      public string userName { get; set; }
      public string client_id { get; set; }
      public DateTime issued { get; set; }
      public DateTime expires { get; set; }

    }
  }
}
```

Which does successfully return the data I'm after but there are issues with the returned data (Removed sensitive data):

```
<z:anyType xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" i:type="d1p1:string">
{"access_token":"XXXXXXXX","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1199,"refresh_token":"XXXXXX","userName":"XXXXXX","as:client_id":"XXXXX",".issued":"Fri, 20 Sep 2019 13:23:48 GMT",".expires":"Fri, 20 Sep 2019 13:43:48 GMT"}
</z:anyType>
```

It also seems to be getting returned as XML instead of JSON?

C# is not my strongest of languages, so I may be completely wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: When you do the same in Javascript, you get JSON?

Comment: I do indeed. In my javascript apps, using the exact same process. The data is returned via JSON. Which I can then access the properties of to authenticate the users. Unfortunately, with the above code in C# the JSON appears to be a 'string' (I assume because of string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() and the actual response appears to be formatted as XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, after you get the JSON string `responseString`, instead of returning it, try the following code.

```
...
string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(responseString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return response;
```

You need to change your method return value from `Task<Object>` to `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`

Edit:

To access the properties, install the Newtonsoft.Json package and try below code.

```
var jsonString = ...
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine(jo["access_token"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, after including your suggestion it now hits the 'Catch' block and says: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage'

Comment: Can you try to debug the code and try to see where the exception was thrown? Sorry that I re-declared the variable **response** and have removed the **var** before it.

Comment: Thankyou so much, as far as I can tell the headers are now being applied and it is being returned as JSON. Another question if I may? How would I now access the properties of the data? I've tried both response.access_token & response["access_token"] both of which give me an error? Also Bizzarely, I had to leavve the Task<Object> as it was? Else I got this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage'

Comment: You can install Newtonsoft.Json package and use the added code in the answer to access the properties.

Comment: HttpRequestException is thrown by HttpClient.PostAsync and in your catch block, do not return the exception, instead, you should handle the exception, e.g. log it and return something like **return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);** or some other error messages to the client.

Comment: Hello, what should jsonString be? I've tried response.Content / response / responseString but all error...

Comment: @AWKingston if you want to access JSON properties from your webapi example code, the jsonString is the same as responseString. If you call your api from a client app, you probably will use the similar HttpClient code, like var response = await client.PostAsync("GetRefreshToken", token); string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Answer (score 2):

One of the things you can do to resolve this is to specifically request a json format on your response by adding the corrent request headers

```
Accept: application/json
```

try it like so

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Now if the server pays attentions to the request headers it will return a json back to you.
It might be defaulting to xml because there is no such header in your request OR the server only supports returning xml responses.

EDIT: If you can not get the server to return json, you can convert your xml string response to json string. Take a look at this [example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJson.htm). After the convertsion you can return your json string normally from your controller.

Edit:

Ok, try out this sample below:

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", ""),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", ""),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", ""),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", ""),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret","")
            });

            AADTokenResponse TokenResponse = null;
            string _baseAddress = string.Format("https://yourTargetDomain.com/");

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseAddress);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("targetApiSegment", content);

                if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var responseString = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    TokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AADTokenResponse>(responseString);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I have tried setting the request headers like this: client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json"); however when viewing the request using Fiddlr the headers dont seem to be added. Also, when I try to use the Task<ActionResult> I get The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found so I added the using System.Web.Mvc; which then produces a new error saying [HttpPost] cannot be found... thankyou!!

Comment: Is this a mvc controller or a web api controller?

Comment: Sorry this is a WebApi controller inheriting from UmbracoApiController

Comment: I think the main issue is that for whatever reason it is coming back as XML not JSON. And no matter what I do the headers will not change so stay as: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3

Comment: Try out this way that i added in the edit. client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

If you do manage to see the header in the request but you still get xml back you can just handle the xml and convert it to json and send it back, see the Edit

Comment: Hey, the request is still completely ignoring it and setting the header to: Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8 - this is definately an issue in C# and not the server as the process is exactly the same using the same API Endpoints and the same data. I have NO IDEA how/why it is being returned as XML, the server doesn't even respond with XML when I specifically request XML in my JavaScript implementation.

Comment: One thing i was thinking about is the definition of your "client". Can you post it aswell?

Comment: Sure thing, why definition is: public HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); it was originally: public readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); but I assumed that as I am trying to modify the headers, readonly would be blocking the changes?

Comment: Also, hoping it helps I've edited the original post with the FULL controller code

Comment: Try adding      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
before adding the line i wrote before. If it helped ill edit the answer again and put it in there. There is nothing "weird" with the client, i was afraid you might be adding some configs that we dont see. Try the clear() and let me know again

Comment: Hey, I now have:         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); - still returns as XML and isn't setting the headers :( - Ahhhhh! I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Ok so.... Please try out my new sample, do not use your http client, just use my code block and do the right replacements for your case! let me know how it goes.
Also note some custom classes i have ( AADTokenResponse ). I use them to deserialize to objects, you might need to make yours as well

Comment: Hey, I tried this but I could get AADTokenResponse to stop erroring? This looks like it relates to Azure?

Comment: Yes this is an azure token authentication implementation i made some days ago. It should help you send the proper call tho, with the headers that we are looking for etc. What do you mean by "AADTokenResponse to stop erroring?" You will have to make an other class to map your response if thats what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, `FormUrlEncodedContent` is the wrong choice, and you'd want to use `StringContent` instead, similar to this:

```
var content = new StringContent(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(values), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await client.PostAsync("https://URL.com/Token", content);
```

The reason being, I dont think FormUrlEncodeContent has an overload to accept adding content type.

Another alternative would be to switch to using SendAsync rather than PostAsync, as SendAsync has some additional flexibility.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I tried something similar earlier. When I use your above exmaple I get the error: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Yeah my mistake, I missed that you were using a Dictionary for values. You'd have to flatten the dictionary first, or convert it to a json string.